# Crash on rotation from horizontal to vertical

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using two different layouts for landscape mode and for portrait mode.

After putting hours, I am not able to figure out the problem. 
The application is working perfectly when launched vertically and also works perfectly when it is rotated horizontally.

The app crashes when I rotate back from horizontal to vertical position and select an item from the list.

```
06-16 14:23:33.769 16108-16108/in.udacity.gagan.cinephilia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.udacity.gagan.cinephilia, PID: 16108
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at in.udacity.gagan.cinephilia.DetailActivityFragment$3.onResponse(DetailActivityFragment.java:165)
at in.udacity.gagan.cinephilia.DetailActivityFragment$3.onResponse(DetailActivityFragment.java:148)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Main Activity Callback Function**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id,
    String backDrop,
    String title,
    int darkColor,
    int lightColor) {

DetailActivityFragment displayFrag = (DetailActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                       .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_left);
    if (displayFrag == null) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                mIntent.putExtra("backdrop_path", backDrop);
                mIntent.putExtra("title", title);
                mIntent.putExtra("darkColor", darkColor);
                mIntent.putExtra("lightColor", lightColor);
                startActivity(mIntent);
       }
       else 
            displayFrag.getContent(id, lightColor);}
```

**Detail Activity Fragment Function**

```
public void getContent(String id, int lightColor) {
        fetchMovieDetails(id, lightColor);
    }
```

**FetchMovieDetails Function**

```
private void fetchMovieDetails(final String id, final int color){

    mMovieDetail = null;
    mDetailsList.clear();
    String url = TmdbUrls.MOVIE_URL + id + "?" + BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DATABASE_API_KEY;
    String reviewURL = TmdbUrls.MOVIE_URL + id + TmdbUrls.REVIEW + "?" + BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DATABASE_API_KEY;
    Log.e("TAG", url);

    JsonObjectRequest getDetails = new JsonObjectRequest(url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String imageUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/" + response.getString("backdrop_path");
                String iconImageURL="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/" + response.getString("poster_path");

                String genres = "";
                JSONArray genreArray = response.getJSONArray("genres");

                for (int i = 0; i < genreArray.length(); i++) {
                    String genre = genreArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    if (i != genreArray.length() - 1)
                        genres += genre + ", ";
                    else
                        genres += genre + ".";
                }
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(response.getString("title"));
                mMovieDetail = new MovieDetail(id,
                        response.getString("title"),
                        response.getString("vote_average"),
                        genres,
                        response.getString("release_date"),
                        response.getString("status"),
                        response.getString("overview"),
                        iconImageURL,
                        imageUrl,
                        response.getString("tagline"),
                        response.getString("original_language"),
                        response.getString("runtime"),
                        response.getString("popularity"),
                        response.getString("vote_count")
                );
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .crossFade()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                        .into(mImageView);
                //fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(lightColor));
                mDetailsList.add(mMovieDetail);
                mAdapter = new DetailsAdapter(color, mDetailsList, mReviewList, mTrailersList, getActivity());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                boolean isMovieInDB = ContentProviderHelperMethods
                        .isMovieInDatabase(getActivity(),
                                String.valueOf(mMovieDetail.getId()));
                if (isMovieInDB) {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_like));
                } else {
                    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_like_outline));
                }

                fab.show();
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        boolean isMovieInDB = ContentProviderHelperMethods
                                .isMovieInDatabase(getActivity(),
                                        String.valueOf(mMovieDetail.getId()));
                        if (isMovieInDB) {
                            Uri contentUri = MoviesContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
                            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(contentUri, "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(mMovieDetail.getId())});
                            Snackbar.make(view, getResources().getString(R.string.removed_from_favourites), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                            fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_like_outline));

                        } else {
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_ID, mMovieDetail.getId());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TITLE, mMovieDetail.getTitle());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_RATING, mMovieDetail.getVote_average());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_GENRE, mMovieDetail.getGenre());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_DATE, mMovieDetail.getReleasedate());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STATUS, mMovieDetail.getStatus());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_OVERVIEW, mMovieDetail.getOverview());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_BACKDROP, mMovieDetail.getBackdrop_path());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_VOTE_COUNT, mMovieDetail.getmVotecount());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TAG_LINE, mMovieDetail.getmTagline());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_RUN_TIME, mMovieDetail.getmRuntime());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_LANGUAGE, mMovieDetail.getmLanguage());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_POPULARITY, mMovieDetail.getmPopularity());
                            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_POSTER, mMovieDetail.getPoster_path());

                            getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MoviesContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);

                            Snackbar.make(view, getResources().getString(R.string.added_to_favourites), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

                            fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_like));
                        }
                    }
                });
                fetchTrailerData(id);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            showSnackBar(getString(R.string.error_msg));
        }
    });
    NetworkController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(getDetails);
}
```

**DetailActivityFragment onCreateView**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout_movie_details);

    lightColor = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("lightColor", 0);
    id = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_movie_details);

    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setBackgroundColor(lightColor);
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(lightColor);
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.transparent));
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white));

    mImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    /*fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(lightColor));*/

    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_back));
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_detail);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_share) {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(title), getResources().getString(R.string.share)));
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    fetchMovieDetails(id ,lightColor);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: you need to check if `mCollapsingToolbarLayout` is null it will be garbage collected when you rotate the device

Comment: DetailActivityFragment contains details related to the item selected from the RecyclerView.
So, clicking on the list item should again allocate memory to it right ?

Comment: if DetailActivityFragment gets shown when something is selected yes but the current task before you rotated does not have the reference to that anymore since it was collected. I would move that `getContent` into your oncreateView of the fragment though so that when your fragment gets recreated you have the information which is really your issue

Comment: You're right but onConfigurationChanged() will provide any help ?

Comment: @GhostCat My choice was to suggest editing this question as this question wasn't  sufficient the user just copy pasted the xml and wanted the answer instead of trying. We expect them to write code so that we can provide some improvements or correctness.

Comment: "Edit" means: *anybody* can **fix** the question (make it answerable) by editing. But this question is A) way too broad and B) very unclear (see the comments I gave to the OP). Thus neither "edit" or "ok" are valid here. This question needs to be reworked by the OP **himself**, and therefore closing it (for too broad/unclear) is the only valid choice. I hope that makes sense. In any case, I appreciate the quick and kind comeback.

Comment: Actually I do edit the questions but in this case the only missing thing was the code to implement the functionality. How can I add a code on behalf of him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your real issue is where you call to get your information `displayFrag.getContent(id, lightColor);` Since it looks like your fragment content can change I would not use a static fragment (declared in your layout xml) for this and manually add/replace the fragment when the item is clicked and send your information that the fragment needs to load in the `setArguments()` method

this way when your device rotates you still have the information and in your onCreateView you can just call `getContent(id, lightColor)` and you shouldn't get those error(though I would still check if any of your views are null before you try to use them

Comment: okay, I am getting it. Instead of using <fragment> in xml I should use a FrameLayout and instead of using displayFrag.getContent(id, lightColor);
I should rather create a DetailActivityFragment object and then pass the values as arguments using bundle.  right ?

Comment: that is correct, the only thing you have to worry about then is making sure you show the fragment again in your activity when the device rotates by doing something similar to `DetailActivityFragment displayFrag = (DetailActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                       .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_left);` in your activities onCreate. Just make sure to check if the frame is actually an instance of the fragment or you will get a cast exception

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I am implementing it.

Answer (score -1):

in DetailActivityFragment.java line 165 or 148

```
if(mCollapsingToolbarLayout == null) {
   mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout_movie_details);
 } mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("...")
```

**Or** add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in the manifest

The second approach might not be the best solution for your needs... 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

**Or**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      if(mCollapsingToolbarLayout == null) {
          mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) 
          getActivity().findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout_movie_details);
    } mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("...")
 }
```

Comment: rootView is a local variable to onCreateView.function. 
I changed the code from rootView to getActivity().findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout_movie_details);

it generated this error
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: yeah, its because the activity isn't up at this time... you could override onActivityCreated and then call getActivity().. check the updated answer.

Comment: your third suggestion didn't help :( I am trying the link you've provided.